# PyCharm IDE syntax colouring issue

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting

When setting `TODO` comments in the editor to use any given (ie: yellow) syntax colouring scheme, the aforementioned is also displayed in the sat colour on the console. The problem presents itself when said colour is yellow and the console is white. See image.

I will hate to have to give up my preferred syntax customisation without first working on finding a workaround.

[image: PyCharm Syntax Colouring Issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy workaround, Project View and other panels that have trees use Look&Feel background colors that are not configurable from the PyCharm settings. The only way to make it dark is to use Look&Feel with dark colors and it will not look native on Mac.

Check [IDEA-62247](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-62247) and linked issues for more details.